# Can I transfer my downloaded GTA 5 from PS3 to PC or PS4?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, psn

I bought and downloaded GTA 5 from the Playstation store on my PS3 and I would like to have it on my PC or maybe even PS4. I do not wish to have a duplicate game, if I have GTA 5 on my PC I will definitely not be playing it on the PS3. I understand it is highly unlikely I can transfer my game from PS3 to PC but I can not seem to find anyone else asking the same question and especially can't find the answer. I am not worried about game saves and character progress, I am only asking if I can change the platform of my game just once without any duplication. I would really like to play on PC but if it's not possible I would like to know if it is possible with the PS4. I already bought the game at 59.99, I am asking for the exact same game, just different platform. Sorry if I repeated myself but I wanted to be thorough and detailed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope.  The platform you bought it on is the one you have it on.  There is no way to transfer it to a different platform.  All you can do is buy it for any other platform you wish to play it on.

Comment: Thank you very much. After 2 hours of searching online, my question was answered within a few seconds here. Excellent site. Thanks again.